Display conditional popup in JSF
I have a command button in JSF when it is clicked, it executes some Java code. Before this code is executed I wanna perform some check and when the check returns true I wanna display a popup, how can I achieve this?
I inserted my code on the bottom so when I click this commandButton the doSomething has to run but before the code runs I wanna check some condition and if that evaluates to true I want to display a popup.
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.doSomething}" />


You have not mentioned it clearly whether you want to add the logic (which you wanna evaluate) at front-end side or back-end side. If the evaluation can easily be performed at front-end side, use onclick event on <h:commandButton> as below.
<script>

function evaluateCondition(){
    if(conditionEvaluation){
        alert("Message for POP UP");
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
    
</script>

<h:commandButton
onclick="javascript: return evaluateCondition();"
action="#{bean.doSomething} />

Or if your condition should be evaluated at back-end side, then you can add method in the bean which will take place before your doSomething().
P.S.
Okay, if you want to add the condition check at the back-end side, here is the explanation & code for the same,

Firstly, the popup will be hidden with display: none property. When
submit button is clicked it will call its listener method
evaluateCondition in the bean.
This method will evaluate the condition & update the conditionMet
boolean variable.
When evaluateCondition completes the execution, it will render
conditionMet & popup elements of the front-end to get the latest
value of conditionMet variable from the bean.
handleConditionCheck javascript function will display the popup to
indicate the user that condition is met & clicking Ok will execute
doSomething of the bean.

Note: Based on your jsf version compatibility of the tags may vary.
JSF code
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" id="submitButton">
        <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{bean.evaluateCondition}" render="conditionMet, popup" onevent="handleConditionCheck" />
    </h:commandButton>
    
    <h:outputText id="conditionMet" value="#{bean.conditionMet}" style="display:none;" />

    <h:panelGroup id="popup" layout="block" style="display:none;">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <h:outputText value="Condition Evaluated to true! Click OK to proceed." />
            <h:commandButton value="OK" action="#{bean.doSomething}" onclick="hidePopup();" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleConditionCheck(data) {
        if (data.status === 'success') {
            var conditionMet = document.getElementById("mainForm:conditionMet").innerText;
            if (conditionMet === 'true') {
                document.getElementById("mainForm:popup").style.display = 'block';
            } else { 
                // handle else part as per your requirement.
            }
        }
    }

    function hidePopup() {
        document.getElementById("mainForm:popup").style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>

Bean Code (JAVA)
public class Bean {

    private boolean conditionMet;

    public void evaluateCondition() {
        //Condition logic here
        conditionMet = /* assign the condition result */;
    }

    public boolean isConditionMet() {
        return conditionMet;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        // Do Something logic
    }
}


It should be evaluated in the backend, can you ahow some example in the backend?

It has to be like this: button is clicked, evaluate something in backend, if true , show some popup, after it is clicked away, doSomething() is executed

@YasinEraslan I have updated the answer as you requested for backend, Is it helpful to you? I think this solves your problem.

Hey, it ist looking good, just one thing which is not working, when I am trying to get the property for the evaluation, it is taking the default boolean value false. In my debugger I can see how it is set to true but the jsf is getting it as false.

I dont know if it is about the annotations I have, I got the annotatiosn Named and ViewScoped on top of the BeanClass

@YasinEraslan could you please provide more details on the problem you are facing, like the structure of tags inside your jsf page, some more information of your bean configurations etc.
Or if you've already asked a separate question then you can share the link here.

I got an idea why the problem occurs, lemme check that, will respond to you afterwards
